# Where does ArcMap store ArcGIS Online credentials?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, authentication

ArcMap maintains the stored credentials to ArcGIS Online despite closing the program (and killing the Connection in the taskbar).

How does ArcMap store these credentials?

Comment: Shouldn't this problem go away if you just sign out?

Comment: Yes it would but it must store them somewhere?

Comment: I don't think anyone will tell you that. This is an implementation detail which wouldn't be documented and you are not supposed to know where the credentials are stored and how. Your best shot is to contact Tech Support and see whether they will let you know that. Or maybe someone from Esri will notice this question and comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** It should go without saying, don't mess with your registry if you don't know what you're doing!  I take no responsibility.

It's stored in the Windows Registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\ESRI\ArcGIS Online\SignIn
```

Here is a screenshot of part of mine.

[image]

To test, I made sure I was signed into my ArcGIS Online account and closed ArcMap.  I also had to check that the Connection Manager also closed.

I renamed the registry key to `ArcGIS Onlinexx`, closed REGEDIT and started ArcMap.   I was no longer signed in and the login details were gone.

[image]

I then closed ArcMap again, renamed the key back and restarted ArcMap.  It signed in automatically again.

[image]

---

To take it a step further (I got curious!):

1. I renamed my ArcGIS Online key in the Registry, closed, restarted ArcMap as per above.  I was signed out.
2. I then signed into one of my other ArcGIS Online accounts.
3. Closed ArcMap etc.
4. I renamed the registry key back to the first one and restarted ArcMap, and was signed into the first account.
5. Closed all and switched the key back again and restarted ArcMap and again I was signed into the second account.

If I was needing to switch accounts often I could see benefit in a batch file to populate the correct registry key for whichever account I want to be signed in on.

**Note:** the login credentials are encoded in the Registry - I cannot see the actual Username or Password.